# Python version while running in ubuntu terminal

Tags: version, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5, python-3.7, python-3.8

I have python 3.5, 3.7.1 and 3.8 versions. In ubuntu 16.04 terminal while giving 
         $python -version
It gives an output as 3.7.1
Why not the latest version I have upgraded as 3.8?
[I have attached the problem in picture too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb9kh.png)

Comment: The python command is probably set in your path to v3.7.1. Try typing `python3.8 --version` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, that works but how to change path to move to python3.8 version?